# Python Regex, fix number spacing

Tags: python, regex

I have some paragraphs with malformed text. I need to replace spaces between numbers. For example:

```
6. 7 should be 6.7
```

I have tried the following expression to get at the offending space but it selects `6.`:

```
(?:\d\.)\s(?=\d+)
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\d\.)\s+(?=\d+)
 ^^^
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qA5cP4/1). Or, use a capturing group but replace with a `\1` backreference later:

```
(\d\.)\s+(?=\d+)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW6eQ3/1)

**NOTE**: If these numbered bullet points are at the beginning of the lines, use the `^` anchor at the beginning that will match the beginning of the line if you use a `re.M` flag and you may add `[ \t]*` after the `^` to match 0+ spaces:

```
^([ \t]*\d\.)\s+(?=\d+)
^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS7wW9/1)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^([ \t]*\d\.)\s+(?=\d+)', re.MULTILINE)
s = """6. Some text ending in a number 2. 23-Feb-2012
 6. 1 More text 3. 2017 is a year
  6. 2
   6. 7
"""
res = p.sub(r"\1", s)
print(res)
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/aA79K0)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+\.)\s+(\d+)',r'\1\2','62. 7; 8.5; 6. 912')
'62.7; 8.5; 6.912'
```